# When would spring release spring-kafka version that will be compatible with kafka-clients:3.5.1?

Tags: spring-kafka

I would like to know that When would spring release spring-kafka new version that will be compatible with kafka-clients:3.5.1?

Resolve snappy-java vulnerabilities i.e., kafka-clients:3.5.1 uses latest snappy-java:1.1.10.1, which resolves latest security vulnerabilities (CVE-2023-34455)

Answer (score 0):

Spring versioning rules don't allow changes to minor dependency versions in a patch release.

See the documentation for how to override the versions; all supported versions work with the 3.5.1 clients.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/3.0.10-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#update-deps

If you are not using Boot and its dependency management, you must upgrade all kafka jars to the same version (3.5.1).

The next Boot release 3.2 will automatically pull in the latest clients.

Comment: Currently we are using Spring-boot:2.6.6 and spring-kafka:2.8.4. Please advise if we can still override kafka-clients to version 3.5.1?

Comment: Neither of those versions are currently supported as OSS (use the latest Boot 2.7.x and Spring for Apache Kafka 2.9.x). However,  I do not expect you will have any problems using 3.5.1 with 2.8.x (but you should use the latest, 2.8.11), AS LONG AS YOU ARE NOT using the embedded Kafka broker for testing; there are breaking API changes in the Kafka `TestUtils` class that prevent the 2.8.x embedded broker from starting; we worked around that in 2.9.x.